# How can I return and save a value from a JList, close the window, and open a new one?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I developed a console application card game in Java. Now I need to modify it to add a GUI that will ask for several inputs (like the number of decks that will be used) and then run the card game. So I tried creating a JFrame where the user could choose the number of decks using a JList and then click on a JButton "Next" so a new window appears asking for the next input, but I had some problems in this last part. How can I return and save the value of the first input selected from the JList, close the window, and open a new one where it will do the same asking for the next input?

Comment: `CardLayout`, `JOptionPane`...

Comment: Can you add the code snippet of what you have written already.